# Two SELECT-Statement work alone but not together

Tags: sql, oracle, select, subquery

I have two select statements that work on their own, but not together.

This:

```
SELECT MAX(a2.Fachanzahl)
FROM C17_AbfrageBView a2;
```

works and returns one row with one column with the value 2

This:

```
SELECT a1.PersonID, a1.Vorname, a1.Nachname, MAX(a1.Fachanzahl) Fachanzahl
FROM C17_AbfrageBView a1
GROUP BY a1.PersonID, a1.Vorname, a1.Nachname
HAVING MAX(a1.Fachanzahl) = 2;
```

works and returns the correct row.

However, this:

```
SELECT a1.PersonID, a1.Vorname, a1.Nachname, MAX(a1.Fachanzahl) Fachanzahl
FROM C17_AbfrageBView a1
GROUP BY a1.PersonID, a1.Vorname, a1.Nachname
HAVING MAX(a1.Fachanzahl) = (
                              SELECT MAX(a2.Fachanzahl)
                              FROM C17_AbfrageBView a2
                            );
```

does not return anything (it should return the same row as the above statement), even though the outer and inner select statements work on their own. What is the problem here?

Thank you!

Comment: What returns if you change query: `select * 
from
(SELECT a1.PersonID, a1.Vorname, a1.Nachname, MAX(a1.Fachanzahl) Fachanzahl
FROM C17_AbfrageBView a1
GROUP BY a1.PersonID, a1.Vorname, a1.Nachname) t
where t.Fachanzahl = (
                              SELECT MAX(a2.Fachanzahl)
                              FROM C17_AbfrageBView a2
                            );`

Comment: @l3rutt that works! thank you!

Comment: This code is executed in the same instance? Also if your store the max value into a variable and use the variable on having still returns you wrong output?

Comment: @Petra1999 however we did not find out why your code does not work.

Comment: @Petra1999 this should work: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=28817a3f6ec6d65e68d89a32050fac70 What is the `Fachanzahl` data type?

Comment: This looks like a bug... which version and patch level or Oracle are you on?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot think of a mechanism where this would happen.  As far as I know, `MAX()` does not change the type of a column, ruling out things like float rounding errors or collation incompatibilities.

I *can* say that the query would be more efficient if written using `WHERE` rather than `HAVING`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a1.PersonID, a1.Vorname, a1.Nachname, a1.Fachanzahl
FROM C17_AbfrageBView a1
WHERE a1.Fachanzahl = (SELECT MAX(a2.Fachanzahl)
                       FROM C17_AbfrageBView a2
                      );
```

If the `MAX()` is introducing some problem with nano-changes to the value, then this might fix the problem.

Because you only care about the maximum value (at least in the query in the question), you can filter first.  This makes the query much more efficient.  The difference between `SELECT DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` should be between nothing and negligible.  The former is easier to type.

Comment: My only guess is that the original code fails because of the execution order of the statements.  If the subquery has no value at the point the HAVING clause is evaluated it would give the NULL result the OP sees.

Comment: @ChristianPalmer . . . Oracle should be transaction safe, so changes to the data should not affect the query.

Comment: I didn't mean data changes - just the order the two statements are executed.  It seems obvious that the database should evaluate the subquery first but maybe because of a bug it is not doing so

Comment: @ChristianPalmer . . . That should make no difference.  The maximum value is the maximum value -- quite deterministic I believe.  That maximum value should be in some group.  The types should not change.  It should be possible to find the group using `=`.

Comment: Okay - I am not trying to say what should happen -  of course the statement (however clumsy) should work.  I'm theorising about the type of bug that might cause this problem.